# debugging my code in transporting binary number to a 10-base number

Tags: python, debugging

l tried to transport a binary number(=c) to a number in 10 base, but when l apload it in quera website, it shows error.

```
a=int(input())

b=int(input())

if  0<b<2**30 and 0<a<2**30:

    c =(a^b)

    c=str(c)

    s=0

    i=len(c)

    for n in c: 

    

        n=  int(n)

        s+= n*2**i

        i -=1

z=int(s/2)

print(z)
```

Comment: Your requirement is unclear. Show sample inputs and expected output

Comment: "*when l apload it in quera website, it shows error.*" Please [edit] to also post the exact error message.